# Adding matrix rows to columns in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Say I have two 3D matrices/tensors with dimensions:

```
[10, 3, 1000]
[10, 4, 1000]
```

How do I add each combination of the third dimensions of each vector together such that to get a dimension of:

```
[10, 3, 4, 1000]
```

So each row if you will, in the second x third dimension for each of the vectors adds to the other one in every combination. Sorry if this is not clear I'm having a hard time articulating this...

Is there some kind of clever way to do this with numpy or pytorch (perfectly happy with a numpy solution, though I'm trying to use this in a pytorch context so a torch tensor manipulation would be even better) that doesn't involve me writing a bunch of nested for loops?

Nested loops example:

```
x = np.random.randint(50, size=(32, 16, 512))
y = np.random.randint(50, size=(32, 21, 512))
scores = np.zeros(shape=(x.shape[0], x.shape[1], y.shape[1], 512))

for b in range(x.shape[0]):
    for i in range(x.shape[1]):
        for j in range(y.shape[1]):

            scores[b, i, j, :] = y[b, j, :] + x[b, i, :]
```

Comment: Do you mean `arr1[:, :, None, :] + arr2[:, None, :, :]`?

Comment: Yes...possibly. I posted some sample code where I try to use nested loops, and then I tried your example, but somehow the values are not equal even when the dimensions are the same. I may be making a mistake in my loop, but I just want to make sure your code is doing what I understand it to be doing. Not sure what's happening...

Comment: not a torch user, so I'm afraid I can't help you with that. What does `.data[0]` do?

Comment: oh it just returns the value of the underlying numpy matrix in the tensor...it's not relevant; I can also write it in numpy form but the code there does what it looks like it does, you can ignore the .data[0]. Also size(x) function gives the size of the matrix for dimension x

Comment: actually you might be right...i implemented it in numpy and it is equal...thanks. I am messing up my torch implementation somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Does it work for you?

```
import torch

x1 = torch.rand(5, 3, 6)
y1 = torch.rand(5, 4, 6)

dim1, dim2 = x1.size()[0:2], y1.size()[-2:]
x2 = x1.unsqueeze(2).expand(*dim1, *dim2)
y2 = y1.unsqueeze(1).expand(*dim1, *dim2)

result = x2 + y2

print(x1[0, 1, :])
print(y1[0, 2, :])
print(result[0, 1, 2, :])
```

**Output**:

```
 0.2884
 0.5253
 0.1463
 0.4632
 0.8944
 0.6218
[torch.FloatTensor of size 6]


 0.5654
 0.0536
 0.9355
 0.1405
 0.9233
 0.1738
[torch.FloatTensor of size 6]


 0.8538
 0.5789
 1.0818
 0.6037
 1.8177
 0.7955
[torch.FloatTensor of size 6]
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had an error in my code; otherwise Paul's answer did indeed give me the same results as my loop, with one line, in both torch and numpy. Let me know though if there is something you think I'm overlooking with that line...